# Custom Serilog config possible from Program.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm generating a custom config in ASP.NET Core during the Startup constructor, something like this:

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration) {
    Environment = environment;

    // Add extra config - configs added later override ones added earlier when key names clash
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddConfiguration(configuration)
        .AddXmlFile("appsettings.xml")
        .Build();
}
```

My problem is that, while this new `IConfiguration` can be accessed from `ConfigureServices` and `Configure`, it can't be accessed from the `.UseSerilog()` call in `CreateHostBuilder` (Program.cs). So, I can't access my XML config at the time of my call:

```
webBuilder
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseSerilog((context, config) => {
        config.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
    });
```

How can I get around this? Can I make the new configuration available to the `UseSerilog()` lambda, or can I configure the logger later, in `ConfigureServices()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out I can just `.UseConfiguration()` earlier in the `IWebHostBuilder` chain (instead of in the `Startup` constructor) to pull in my XML config settings:

```
webBuilder
    .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddXmlFile("appsettings.xml").Build())
    .UseSerilog((context, config) => {
        config.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
    })
```